# Trouble with python Homework

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am so close to grasping this. In my code I'm facing an error when trying to split (' , ') with the whitespace. All of my other code works but I am unable to get a response when I use the whitespace first.

```
string = input('Enter input string: \n')
while ',' not in string:
    print('Error: No comma in string.')
string = input('Enter input string: \n')
while string != 'q':
if (', ') in string:
    names = string.split(', ')
    print('First word:',  names[0])
    print('Second word:', names[1])
elif (',') in string:
    names = string.split(',')
    print('First word:',  names[0])
    print('Second word:', names[1])
else:
    names = string.split(' , ')
    print('First word:',  names[0])
    print('Second word:', names[1])

string = input('\n\nEnter input string: \n')
```

Comment: Fix the indentation. Not sure where that second `while` belongs

Comment: Along with what @smac89 said, see how the string looks like. Are the elements seperated by `, ` or  ` ,` or just `,` (notice the spaces) and then use split accordingly.

Comment: Also your first while loop will run indefinitely if the the initial string does not contain a `,`

Comment: @smac89 im thinking the `string=input()` part probably belonged in his first while loop

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj, I'm trying to seperate Jill, Allen
Golden , Monkey
 Washington,DC
I've successfully done the first and the third, but the whitespace between Golden(space),(space)monkey is tripping me up

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the strictest requirement first. In this case, that's the comma with spaces on both sides of it. So reorder your `if`s like this:

```
if " , " in string:
    ...
elif ", " in string:
    ...
else: # "," in string
    ...
```

Or better yet, adjust the rest of the code so that you don't need to treat those three cases differently. For instance, you could split on just the comma, then `strip` the resulting strings so that any whitespace doesn't cause problems:

```
names = [name.strip() for name in string.split(',')]
```